# Translating an Apache .htaccess file to an IIS web.config

Tags: apache, iis, .htaccess, web-config, webserver

I developed an application on my local using PHP, MySQL and Apache and it has a .htaccess file containing this:

```
#Setting the default handler.
  DirectoryIndex home.do

<IfModule mod_mime.c>
  #Supporting .do extensions    
     AddType application/x-httpd-php .do
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  #Removing .do file extension if necessary
     RewriteEngine on
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.do -f
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.do
</IfModule>
```

But I informed that my customer's web server is IIS and I have to use a web.config file instead of .htaccess. Can anyone direct me through this, please?

Answer (score 4):

This could be seen as cheating, but we use [ISAPI_Rewrite](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/), which lets you just use the .htaccess file for IIS. If you can get them to put it on the server, you won't need to translate anything.

Answer (score 3):

Please be aware that this will only  work on IIS7 and **not** on IIS6. Also [this requires FastCGI to be setup](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/246/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis-70/) and [the URL Rewriting module](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-url-rewrite-module/) to be installed and enabled. These are things your hoster will be able to verify for you. If all of the above is true then the following file should do the trick ( you might need to tweak the paths but again I think your hoster will be able to do this for you if you supply them with this example file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="system.webServer">
            <sectionGroup name="rewrite">
                <section name="rewriteMaps" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
                <section name="rules" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>

<system.webServer>
    <!-- Mapping the .do extension to the PHP ISAPI module -->
    <handlers>
        <!-- the following line is very specific to your host
             please check the module name and the scriptProcessor 
             path with the system administrator! basically this is 
             the same as
             http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/246/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis-70/#EnableFastCGI
             only in .config format. -->
        <add name="MaskDoAsPHP" path=".do" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\PHP\php-cgi.exe" />
    </handlers>

    <!-- Setting the default handler. -->
    <defaultDocument>
        <files>
            <clear />
            <add value="home.do" />
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>

    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Removing do extension" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{R1}.do" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: thanks olle and im sorry for the late reply! I'm done finally, your code helped :D

Comment: Ok good, if you let me know what was "wrong" with it I can update the awnser for future visitors.

Answer (score 2):

IIS7 and above can import Apache .htaccess rules using the **URL Rewrite module**.

1. Install the [URL Rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/downloads?tabid=34&g=6&i=1691) via the *Microsoft Web Platform Installer*
2. Start IIS Manager and on the left, in the Connections pane, select your required site (e.g. Default Web Site)
3. In the centre (Features View) double click **URL Rewrite**.
4. In the right panel click **Import Rules...** then paste your rules from the .htaccess file into the **Rewrite rules** box
5. Click apply in the right column.